# Long last name gets cut off from embeddable profile

Tags: bug, flair

My last name gets cut off on my embedded flair, as shown here:

[image]

Not sure if this is already a known issue, nor a fix. If this is cruft, I can delete the question.

Comment: It's actually a subtle hint, Mr. I'm So Important My Name is Five Miles Long

Comment: Glass house, rocks, Mr. William Alistair Fulbright Roosevelt Hildebrand Rodrigo Giacomo van Sullivan Saxe-Gotha-Coburg!

Comment: I've been found out!  Damn your eyes, sir!

Comment: @SeanC that's not the same problem. The display name has to fit in the design of the site, the flair is meant for external websites so the width doesn't really matter.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39689/long-display-names-cause-flair-layout-issue Looks like it is purposely truncated